# Ubuntu 15.10 server - nameserver config broken after reboot

Tags: networking, ubuntu, gateway, network-interface

After a reboot, I can't resolve any hostnames anymore.

Well, the Ubuntu system, is running within an VMWare server, it shouldn't matter.

The config under `/etc/network/interfaces` contains:

```
auto ens160
iface ens160 inet static
address 172.16.194.4
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 172.16.194.5
```

It's been working before.

`route -n` is showing this:

```
Destination     Router          Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.194.5    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens160
172.16.194.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens160
```

The command `sudo route add default gw 172.16.194.5 ens160` results with an error:

```
SIOCADDRT: file already exists
```

What could be wrong? Everything I try fails...

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem by myself:
I had to add in `/etc/network/interfaces` a line with the nameservers:

```
 dns-nameservers 172.16.194.5 172.16.194.200
```

After restarting the network with `sudo service networking restart`, it worked.